# Button_to uses POST Link_to uses GET, why? ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I've ran into a ror problem using the link_to. Why does my link to use the GET method and my button_to use the POST method, after I specified my "method"=>"post" within the link_to parameters?

View:

```
<%= button_to "pdf", :action => 'getquote' %>
<%= link_to 'pdf', {:controller => 'inventories', :action => 'getquote', :method => :post } %>
```

Controller Method:

```
def getquote
@cart = find_cart
respond_to do |format|
format.pdf
end
end
```

Terminal Output (Button/Link, respectively):

```
Processing InventoriesController#getquote (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-01-30 01:38:02) [POST]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"getquote", "authenticity_token"=>"D2cwnHyTHgomdUM3wXBBXlOe4NQLmv1Srn0paLbExpQ=", "controller"=>"inventories"}

Processing InventoriesController#show (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-01-30 01:39:07) [GET]
  Parameters: {"method"=>"post", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"getquote", "controller"=>"inventories"}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your html options have to be in a separate hash from your url options:

```
<%= link_to 'pdf', {:controller => 'inventories', :action => 'getquote'}, {:method => :post } %>
```

I looked all over for a proper example, with no luck. For my code, I've mostly given up and just use the new style:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', custom_event, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: I'm having this same problem with ROR 3.0.17 (or 18, or 19, don't remember). I made the markup just like this "new style" it's working on most pages except one specific page. The call is the exact same thing, I don't know what's wrong. Also firebug shows that the link has 2 data parameter: data-confirm and data-method. Is this supposed to be right?

Answer (score 8):

Might be useful for someone who is visiting :)

By default, button_to performs POST action only.

to do make a GET the syntax is as follows:

```
<%= button_to 'pdf', { :action => 'getquote'}, :method => :get %>
```

Comment: Does work, but only if you pass `:get` as a symbol or lowercase `"get"`. String `"GET"` doesn't work. Just a little gotcha.

Comment: When I do this it add a question mark "?" to the end of my URL. Anyone else see this or have a fix?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that you have Javascript disabled, in which case it will fall back to a GET.